# How to make up and down motion in phaser js without gravity

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Newbie: I am following this  [tutorial](http://www.photonstorm.com/phaser/tutorial-making-your-first-phaser-game)

I tried adding up and down motion also like:

```
if (cursors.left.isDown) {
    //  Move to the left
    player.body.velocity.x = -150;
    player.animations.play('left');
} else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
    //  Move to the right
    player.body.velocity.x = 150;
    player.animations.play('right');
}else if (cursors.up.isDown) {
   // Move to the top
   player.body.velocity.y = -50;
   player.animations.play(‘top’);
} else if (cursors.down.isDown) {
   // Move to the bottom
   player.body.velocity.y = 50;
   player.animations.play(‘bottom’);
}
```

The character is moving but when we press up arrow key, player will go till top of the game screen, and when down arrow is pressed it will fall from top. I tried setting `player.body.gravity.y = 0;` still it falls down or flies up. Lelt and right motion is perfect, I need a similar behavior when moving up or down.

Comment: Nice framework... Have you tried specifying positive gravity? Like `6` for example?

Comment: If I specify a positive gravity it will begin to fall from top on document ready(game load).

Comment: So, there is an update loop where this code is running. Have you tried specifying `player.body.velocity.y = 0;` at the beginning of your `update()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you're not clearing `velocity.y` in your `update` function like this:

```
function update() {
    player.body.velocity.x = 0;
    player.body.velocity.y = 0;
    // below is your code from the question
}
```

Comment: if I specify velocity as 0 
player.body.velocity.y = 0; then it will not move even if we press the up/down keys

Comment: Have you tried debugging `update` function and see if values are set correctly? How often does `update` fire?

Comment: Thanks you were absolutely correct, I was not setting velocity.y = 0; Didn't notice it when you mentioned it first.